# Installing Ubuntu 11.10 on laptop with Ubuntu9.04 

Tags: 11.10, boot-failure

I have Ubuntu 9.04 currently and I can't get the Ubuntu 11.10 install disk to work.

When I boot the 11.10 disc it hangs with the message: `ISOLINUX 4.04 20110518 ETCD Copyright (C) 1994-2011 H.Peter Anvin et al`

I also tried to insert disc once the computer was started up and tried to boot from there but nothing happened.

I opened the files on the disc and clicked on `wubi.exe`, which then gives three options. I chose the "Install Ubuntu" option and when I click on reboot now it does not respond.

I ordered the Ubuntu disc so it can't be a bad burn.

Comment: Please add further information. What's the issue with your 11.10 installation disk?

Comment: What do you mean by the install disk not working? Black screen? Error message? Please edit your post to describe what you're experiencing.

Comment: Hi Ria :-) Can you try boot this CD on another PC and tell us what happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a bad burn/image.

I'd suggest to wait 2 days since 12.04 will be out on 4/26/2012 then try burning that image at a slower speed.

But if you want to use 11.10 right now, you should redownload the ISO and to make sure it's not a bad image verify it with MD5SUM(i never needed to do this so this can be optional)
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

then burn it to a new CD-R or CD-RW.

Still doesn't work? 11.10 could be incompatible with your machine, so try 12.04 in a couple days. Good luck!

Comment: Its a disc I got from Ubuntu so it can't be defect is there no way to force it to install?